# Read File assembly language

Tags: file, assembly, byte

I'm writing this file in assembly language and it reads a file which is 64,000 bytes long. I don't want to store it in RAM so I need to make it so that it reads one byte, manipulates the data, then store the next byte at the same address.

Any Ideas?

I am running on a MS-DOS boot disk on windows XP hardware (I don't know the specs) when ever I run it where I store the 64,000 I get an EMM error telling me I need to reboot.

Comment: Can you post the relevant assembly?

Comment: I'm guessing you're in realmode x86? There's no reason any "modern" assembly language program can't handle more than 64k of data, especially now that protected mode 64bit is the defacto standard... As well, unless you specify which OS+cpu you're running under, and what mode, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: I don't see any reason why 64000 bytes should cause any problems. Where are you storing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DOS int 21h function 48h to allocate](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2934.htm) 64000 bytes of memory. It allocates memory in multiples of 16 bytes, so you pass it 64000/16=4000 in `BX`.

On return from that function `AX` will contain the segment of the allocated block, which you will have to load into a segment register (`DS`, `ES`, `FS` or `GS`) before accessing that block. If you load it into a segment register other than `DS`, you will need to prefix the instructions accessing the block with the segment override prefix, like so:

`mov [es:0], al` -- stores `AL` to the very first byte of the block (the block's segment is in `ES`).

When you're done using the allocated memory, you free it using [function 49h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2935.htm).